# Creating carousel with elements/divs inside?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, carousel

I want to create an *carousel* with different 8 items. Those 8 times contains different `div`s, paragraphs and images and user should see 4 items on one "slide" so, I have to create new `div`s to wrap that all.

Right now I am using Flexslider by WooCommerece:
http://flexslider.woothemes.com/basic-carousel.html

But sadly this Felixslider isn't working with `div`s.

My question now is, which slider is supporting `div`s, paragraphs and images?

Also, I have to create the `div`s with PHP. But, that I could do myself.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use this [Demo](https://www.sitepoint.com/making-simple-image-slider-html-css-jquery/)

and you can create your own extension like this [Demo](https://www.sitepoint.com/making-simple-image-slider-html-css-jquery/)

Comment: Thanks, working now! :) But how can I set the right size for each item for the different solutions? Below 1122px it is looking shitty... (At the bottom of the page: https://classymagazin.de/artikelseite-template/)

Comment: which slider you used? and can you also change this itemMargin to 3 show slider show next and previous image when use click on both button

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [Owl carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html) would work for you. Checkout the [demo of owl carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html)